# How to return result of db from a nested functions in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want the result on other file but not getting how to return it

```
function getUsers(){
console.log("Fetching all user data");

const connection = getConnection();
const sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
var result = connection.query(sql,(err, rows, fields) =>{

    if(err){
        console.log("Failed to get users data");
        res.sendStatus(500);
        throw err;
    }

    console.log("Fetched Users Successfully");
    return rows;
})

return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard asynchronous function problem. 
`return rows` will not assign rows to the `result` variable. Second argument of `query()` function is a callback function and it indicates a block of code that will be executed after rows are fetched. It means that result of the query is only visible inside callback block.

You can fix it in 2 ways:

1. Write all your code that uses SQL result inside callback function block (You can call another function at that point and pass result as argument for example).
   This method is simpler if you are new to javascript programming. I see that you want to use function `getUsers()` in another place. If you choose this approach, best way would probably be to pass a callback to the `getUsers()` function and then invoke it in the callback of the `query()` method.

Example:

```
getUsers(callback){
   const connection = getConnection();
   const sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
   connection.query(sql,(err, rows, fields) => callback(rows))
}  
mainFunction(req,res){ 
   getUsers(doSomethingWithUsers)
 }

doSomethingWithUsers(users){
  ...
}
```

This is of course, oversimplified pattern, but the idea should be clear.

2. Research about promises and how they handle async functions. This will require you to "wrap" you function body into `Promise` object type.
   They will allow you to write something like this:

   mainFunction(){
     getUsers().then(result => ....);
     // or even
     const users = await getUsers();
   }

EDIT:
To wrap "return value of promise", or as we say "to resolve a promise", you can wrap function the following way:

```
function getUsers(){
  console.log("Fetching all user data");

  const connection = getConnection();
  const sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
  return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    var result = connection.query(sql,(err, rows, fields) =>{
      if(err){
        // this will cause promise to "fail"
        reject(err);
      }
      console.log("Fetched Users Successfully");
      // this will tell javascript that promise is finished
      // and rows are accesable in then() 
      resolve(rows);
   })
  })
}

function mainFunction(){
  const result = getUsers()
  .then(rows =>{/** this will happen if resolve(rows) is called */})
  .catch(error => {/** this will be executed if reject(err) happens 
   */}); 
}

// or... (Try/Catch is required since "await" silently fails
async function asyncMainFunction(){
 try{
 const rows = await getUsers();
 // You can use rows from resolve() here;
 }catch(error){
  // here, reject is called
 }

}
```

Here is a link where you can read more about promises:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: How can i use promises in this function? please also describe that with my code

Comment: I added example in my answer

Answer (score 1):

create file for function : `getUsers.js`

```
 module.exports = async getUsers(){

    const connection = getConnection();
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

    var myPromise = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.query(sql, query.params, function (error, results, fields) {
                error ? reject(error) : resolve(results);
            })

        });
    }
    var result = await (myPromise());
    return result;
}
```

require this file and call function :

```
var getUsers = require('..path to getUsers');

var data =  getUsers().then((data)=>{

}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log('error',error)
    return error;
});
```

using callback :

or using callback function :

```
 module.exports = function getUsers(callback){

const connection = getConnection();
const sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

  connection.query(sql, query.params, function (error, results, fields) {
      if(error){ callback(error,null)}  
      if(!error && results){
         callback(null,results)
      }
  });
}
```

require file :

```
var getUsers = require('..path to getUsers');
```

call it this way :

```
getUsers(err,data)=>{
   if(err){
      return res.send(err);
   }
   if(!err && data){
     return res.send(data);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the result because the code is asynchronous. So, you have to use async/await to get the result. Your code should look like this:-

```
async function getUsers(){
console.log("Fetching all user data");

const connection = await getConnection();
const sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
try {
var result = await connection.query(sql);
console.log("Fetched Users Successfully");
return result;
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Failed to get users data");
    res.sendStatus(500);
    throw err;
}

}
```

Finally, call this function like this:-

```
var output = await getUsers();
```

But make sure that you call this line in an async function. 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUsers(callback) {
    console.log("Fetching all user data");
    const connection = getConnection();
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    connection.query(sql, (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Failed to get users data");
            res.sendStatus(500);
            callback(err, null);
        }

        console.log("Fetched Users Successfully");
        callback(null, rows)
    })
}

// USE ABOVE FUNCTION AS BELOW...

getUsers(function(err, rows) {
    if(err){
        console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(rows);
})
```